# Activity Destroyed Fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

i'm developing an app, but i've faced a problem,

I am replacing from fragment 1 to 3 in the activity b each time a broadcast is received, if a button is clicked the app return to the activity a, but when i tried to go to activity b again an error ocurred

FATAL EXCEPTION: main ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

I've been reading and many peoplo fixed it with this:

```
try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

but in my case it didn't work.

here's my fragment managing code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmento_2 fragment2 = new fragmento_2();
                Bundle m = new Bundle();
                m.putInt("numero_cuenta", tempo);
                fragment2.setArguments(m);
                ft.replace(R.id.layout,fragment2);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();




             FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmento_3 fragment3 = new fragmento_3();
        Bundle n = new Bundle();
        n.putInt("numero_cuenta",tempo);
        fragment3.setArguments(n);
        ft.replace(R.id.layout,fragment3);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();



    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmento_1 fragment1 = new fragmento_1();
    ft.add(R.id.layout, fragment1);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

thanks

Comment: I ran into this problem the other day and can't wrap my head around this. Any chance you figured out the solution? I has been a few years since you posted this!